# FQL to retrieve upcoming birthdays

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to retrieve the upcoming birthdays from Facebook via the FQL

Is there a way to do it?

I have tried searching it online, but couldn't get a working version of it.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the users Birthday or his friends Birthday ? Please can you be more specific about it!

Comment: Hi, I am trying to retrieve the upcoming birthdays for my friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get access to friends birthdays you have to request `friends_birthday` permissions.  Once that is done, you can get each friend's birthday by `select name, birthday from user where uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())`  From this list you can see some people have nulls (the ones who didn't share their birthday with the authenticated user), some have just month/day and some have full month/day/year.  So it'll be up to you to accurately parse these.  Happy coding!!

Answer (score 2):

To parse the date, use something like following condition but it provides birthdays only up to december:

```
$fromDate = date('m/d');
```

```
"SELECT uid, name, birthday, birthday_date,substr(birthday_date,0,3)
 FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
     AND birthday_date>='$fromDate'  order by birthday_date"
```